# Mongoose: use schema of other model

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a model 'Template'

```
var Schema = new mongoose.Schema({
tId: { type: Number, unique: true },
type: {
    type: String, required: true},
devName: { type: String, required: true, trim: true },
subject: { type: String, required: true, trim: true },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Template', schema, "template");
```

I want to maintain it's history in another model, 'TemplateHistory'
I don't want to write the schema again as,

```
var HistorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
id: number,
template:{
    tId: { type: Number, unique: true },
    type: {
        type: String, required: true},
    devName: { type: String, required: true, trim: true },
    subject: { type: String, required: true, trim: true }
}
});
```

How can I use my Template Schema in HistorySchema above?

Answer (score 0):

Try to map it like this

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var HistorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
id: number,
templateId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Template', required: true }

});
//add virtual 

HistorySchema.set('toObject', { virtuals: true });
HistorySchema.set('toJSON', { virtuals: true });

HistorySchema.virtual('template', {
    ref: 'Employee',
    localField: 'templateId',
    foreignField: '_id',
    justOne: true
});
```

In your service or controller :

```
HistorySchema
.find({})
.populate('template')
.exec( function(err, history)
    {
      res.json(history); // history[0].template
    });
```

Comment: I want complete schema not just templateId

Comment: you just map the id and than you populate your selection